# Подсчет процессов в поддереве

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu

**Дано PID процесса, нужно узнать количество процессов, для которых данный PID является PPID-ом**.

Как это реализовать с помощью утилиты ps (или какой то другой).

Comment: Тело вопроса намекает, что вы хотите посчитать только прямых потомков (детей): `sum(1 for _ in process.children())`, но заголовок о "поддереве" говорит: `sum(1 for _ in process.children(recursive=True))`, где `process = psutil.Process(pid)` (язык Питон). Отредактируйте вопрос и уточните какой результат хотите. Не совсем ясно почему [c] метка, если внешние утилиты вызываете.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ps -h --ppid 1 | wc -l
```

Ключи ps: `-h` без заголовка (что бы его за процесс не посчитать), `--ppid` выдать процессы с заданным ppid. Вывод ps подаем `wc`, которая умеет считать строки.

Что бы получить количество всех потомков рекурсивно можно воспользоватся pstree и немного поколдовать:

```
pstree -p 1 | grep -oP '\(\d+\)' | tail -n +2 | wc -l
```

`pstree` рисует дерево процессов начиная с указанного. К сожалению дерево слишком красивое и считать по нему не удобно. Ключ `-p` дает на дереве pid процессов в круглых скобках. Эти скобки мы выбираем с помощью grep. Пропускаем первую строку `tail`, так как это сам процесс с которого мы начали. И наконец считаем. Но возможны ошибки в случае если в системе есть процесс называющийся одними цифрами в круглых скобках (что в принципе маловероятно)

Comment: ок, а если нужно узнать количество не только прямых потомков?

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку метка С, то может быть кому-нибудь пригодится программа, которая решает данную задачу для всего дерева потомков заданного процесса.

Возьмем в качестве основы список пар PPID, PID всех процессов, получаемый командой
`ps -e -o ppid,pid`
 и отсортируем его по значению PPID. Таким образом все потомки каждого процесса окажутся рядом.

Найдем в этом списке всех прямых потомков заданного процесса (т.е. те пары в списке, у которых PPID равен заданному PID) и поочередно выполним такой же поиск для каждого из них (будем обходить дерево процессов "в ширину"). Для реализации шагов нашего поиска используем очередь PID-ов, в которую помещаем найденных прямых потомков.

Результат (количество потомков заданного процесса) будет равен количеству помещенных в очередь (извлеченных из нее) элементов, за минусом заданного процесса, инициализирующего очередь для обхода дерева.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  pid_t inipid = atoi(av[1] ? : "0");
  if (kill(inipid, 0) && errno == ESRCH)
    exit((puts("No such process"), 1));

  // сортируем по ppid, таким образом все потомки одного pid окажутся рядом
  FILE *in = popen("ps -e --no-headers -o ppid,pid | sort -n -k 1", "r");
  if (!in)
    exit((perror("ps ..."), 2));

  int ppasize,
    nppa = 0;   // количество пар ppid,pid (всего процессов из ps -e)
  struct pids {
    pid_t ppid, pid;
  } *ppa = (__typeof__(ppa))malloc(sizeof(*ppa) * (ppasize = 100));
  if (!ppa)
    exit((perror("malloc"), 2));

  // прочтем отсортированный по ppid набор ppid,pid в ppa[]
  while (fscanf(in, "%d %d", &ppa[nppa].ppid, &ppa[nppa].pid) == 2) 
    if (++nppa == ppasize)
      if (!(ppa = (__typeof__(ppa))realloc(ppa, sizeof(*ppa) * (ppasize *= 2))))
        exit((perror("realloc"), 2));
  pclose(in);

  /* 
     Пройдем по дереву потомков inipid и подсчитаем их число.
     Для этого используем очередь.
     Для pid из головы очереди ищем в ppa[] все процессы с таким ppid
     (это непосредственные потомки) и помещаем их в хвост очереди.
     Повторяем, пока в очереди что-то есть.
     Количество элементов выбранных из очереди является ответом (-1 inipid)
  */
  pid_t q[nppa + 1];  // очередь потомков inipid
  int qh = 0, qt = 0, // индексы head и tail очереди
    nchilds = -1;     // наш result
  q[qt++] = inipid;   // инициируем процесс поиска, занеся в очередь inipid

  // повторяем, пока очередь не станет пустой
  do {
    nchilds++;
    pid_t pid = q[qh++]; // новый parent
    int  first = 0, last = nppa, mid;

    // используем binsearch для поиска первого потомка (ppa[i].ppid == pid)
    while (first < last) {
      mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
      // такое вычисления middle позволяет избегать overflow в общем случае
      if (pid > ppa[mid].ppid)
        first = mid + 1;
      else
        last = mid;
    }
    // переберем всех потомков pid и занесем их в очередь
    // они расположены последовательно, поскольку мы сортировали ppa[] по ppid
    while (first < nppa && pid == ppa[first].ppid)
      q[qt++] = ppa[first++].pid;

  } while (qh < qt);

  free(ppa);
  return printf("pid %d has %d childs (of %d total pids)\n",
                inipid, nchilds, nppa) < 0;
}
```

P.S.
Приведение типа для `malloc`/`realloc` через `__typeof__` сделано для того, чтобы программа транслировалась также и С++ компилятором.

Answer (score 1):

Подсчет всех потомков процесса:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 300

int countProc(int pid)
{
    int count = 0;
    char cmd[MAX_SIZE];
    FILE *fd;   

    sprintf(cmd, "ps -o %%p --ppid %d", pid); 
    fd = popen(cmd, "r");
    fscanf(fd, "%*s");

    int id; 
    while(fscanf(fd, "%d", &id) != EOF)
    {
        count++;
        count += countProc(id);
    }

    pclose(fd);

    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Error!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int pid = atoi(argv[1]);

    int count = countProc(pid) + 1; 

    printf("%d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```